# Как узнать количество допустимых потоков в OpenCL

Tags: opencl

Использую видеокарту. Необходимо выделить глобальную память под все задействующиеся потоки, чтобы каждый обращался к своей памяти, но как это можно сделать? С помощью какой именно функции на хосте?

Comment: Похожий вопрос в течении месяца уже был.

Comment: @nick_n_a нет, всё изучаю opencl)

Comment: @nick_n_a Все правильно. Это разные вещи. OpenCL (от англ. Open Computing Language — открытый язык вычислений) — фреймворк для написания компьютерных программ, связанных с параллельными вычислениями на различных графических и центральных процессорах, а также FPGA.

Answer (score 2):

Ответил в итоге на свой вопрос. 
Когда находим количество устройств - `device`.
То просто узнаем свойство `CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS`

```
    int num;
    devices[0].getInfo(CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS, &num);
    cout << num << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Никак не надо выделять память "под потоки" (нитями их иногда называют).

1. Количество нитей - **любое**, задаётся на хосте (у меня - миллионы; *никакого отношения к количеству ядер GPU не имеет - об этих ядрах вообще **нигде** думать не надо!*). По сути это размер "большого" цикла, который явным образом НЕ пишется. Хотя может быть цикл по одному, двум или 3 измерениям. Только на хосте задаётся размер "большого" цикла по каждому из трёх измерений (или по одному, например).
2. Нити условно разбиваются на "рабочие группы", в каждой примерно по 256-1024нити (зависит от железа - надо его опрашивать). Можно вручную не задавать размер раб.групп по 3 измерениям, но если задаёте, то надо следить, чтобы **им** были кратны размеры "большого цикла" (ограничение OpenCL 1.2 !).
3. Есть 3 вида памяти:
   **-global**, самая медленная, размер задаётся на хосте (**buffer**), ограничен только памятью видеокарты;
   **-local**, быстрая, размер обычно до 32КБайт (зависит от видяхи тоже) - для обмена информацией внутри рабочей группы нитей - размер тоже задаётся на хосте;
   **- private** - самая быстрая, но доступ к ней имеет только данная раб. нить, она определяется уже внутри Kernel.
   Увы, в OpenCL 1.2 нет динамического выделения памяти внутри Kernel.